# Responsive onesite website padding to centre

Tags: html, css, django

Im currently working on making onesie scrolling website but i came accross the problem. I want my text be on the centre of first "page" but i cant make it to looks good on phone and desktop at the same time.
With padding-top: 50% it looks good at mobile but terrible at desktop, on the other hand padding-top: 7 looks good on desktop but not much at phone. Can someone help me finding the golden mean?

[image: padding 50%]
[image: also padding 50%]

my html code:

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main section.page1 {
  background: #81D4FA;
}

.main section.page2 {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.main section.page3 {
  background: #81D4FA;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 8vw;
  color: #efefef;
  text-align: top;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

h2
{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

a.read-more{
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


.notnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section class="page1"> 
    <h1>
      ABOUT ME
      <li class="notnav">
        I am John, 19 years old computer science student. Mainly coding in python, but I am quick lerner and flexible person. I am currently intrested in Artificial Intelligence, Big Data and Design 
      </li>
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <a class="read-more" href='/about'>Read More</a>
    </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="page2">        
     <h1>
      PROJECTS
    </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="page3"> 
    <h1>
      CONTACT
    </h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You should consider using media-query to your css. Otherwise, it won't ever be responsive You can set li without ul or ol

Comment: try doing: `.main section.page1 {display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:center;}` remove the `padding-top` in the h1.

Comment: @Julio thanks that worked. Also thanks to MaxiGui for sure i’ll try media-query, haven’t heard of it before but it looks promising

Comment: @bazzuk123 check my answer

Comment: @bazzuk123 Read about flexbox, I use it a lot!

Comment: he should just use bootstrap, as a beginner it is a huge help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this(without the use of media-query);Sorry late to the party

```
section {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.main section.page1 {
background: #81D4FA;
  }

 .main section.page2 {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    }

   .main section.page3 {
   background: #81D4FA;
   }

   .page1{
  display:flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 flex-direction: column;
justify-content:center;
}

h1 {
font-size: 8vw;
color: #efefef;    
   }

    h2
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   font-size: 4vw;
   color: #efefef;
   text-align: center;
   }

  a.read-more{
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  }
  .notnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 3vw;
    clear: both;
   }
```

Comment: Someone in a comment posted similar answear. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Using media-query makes code longer, happy you loved it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, here is example of adaption for `section.page1` with **Media queries**. This is what you should use to make your code adapting and responsive.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px){
      section {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
      section.page1{
        padding: 20px;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 8vw;
        color: #efefef;
        text-align: top;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 15%;
      }
    }
```

Here is a large explication about it : [Mozilla Developper Using_media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Get more practice and Examples with [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

You can also use bootstrap to get easy css with their grid system : [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main section.page1 {
  background: #81D4FA;
}

.main section.page2 {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.main section.page3 {
  background: #81D4FA;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 8vw;
  color: #efefef;
  text-align: top;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

h2
{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

a.read-more{
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


.notnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px){
  section {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  section.page1{
    padding: 20px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 8vw;
    color: #efefef;
    text-align: top;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section class="page1"> 
    <h1>
      ABOUT ME
    </h1>
    <div class="notnav">
        I am John, 19 years old computer science student. Mainly coding in python, but I am quick lerner and flexible person. I am currently intrested in Artificial Intelligence, Big Data and Design 
      </div>
    <h2>
      <a class="read-more" href='/about'>Read More</a>
    </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="page2">        
     <h1>
      PROJECTS
    </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="page3"> 
    <h1>
      CONTACT
    </h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: this creates bugs in my code, "pages" exepts first one have very short lenght, but I see the concept of this solution. In my understanding this madia query is something like if statment, when your screen width is over 640 px it changes code.  Am i thinking right?

Comment: Yes, here I set 640px first, but you can set for 400px, or any width you wish. You can also create more than 1 media query. The example I made is really basic from your code ( I was not going to fix your whole page). I guess, you need to practice

Comment: @bazzuk123 Those media query width are called break-point. because this is where your css would "break" to give priority on the css you wish. I guess your question is answered.